# Calculating the area of a circle in Java

Tags: java, constructor, geometry

I need to write a program to calculate the area of a circle and I seem to have everything right except when I run the program and input the values the area calculation comes up as zero.

```
public class Circle {

    private double radius;
    private double area;

    public Circle() {
        radius = 0;
        area = 0;
    }

    public Circle(double radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public double getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }

    public void setRadius(double radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public double getArea() {
        return area;
    }

    public void setArea(double area) {
        area = radius * radius * Math.PI;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "The radius of the circle is: " + radius + ", and the area is: " + area;
    }
}
```

What do I need to change so that when my test code calls the toString it will output a calculated area?

Comment: Have you called `setArea`? Your design is wrong.

Comment: I don't see any part that fetches input to feed it to the `Circle` instance. We need to see it too.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/RYUFY7AQ

Comment: Your `setArea` method doesn't set the class `area` variable. Use `this.area =...` or else you're just overwriting your input parameter.

Comment: area and radius should be correlated. If you set the area to a given value, it should also set the radius. And if you set the radius, it should also set the area. Otherwise, you'll have a circle wich has a radius of 1 and an area of 10000, and your circle won't be a circle anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a method calculate area based on the current radius.  Area should not be set.

```
public class Circle {
    private double radius;

    public Circle() {
        radius = 0;
    }

    public Circle(double radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public double getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }

    public void setRadius(double radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public double getArea() {
        return calculateArea();
    }

    private double calculateArea() {
        return radius * radius * Math.PI;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "The radius of the circle is: " + radius + ", and the area is: "
                + calculateArea();
    }
}
```

If you did wish to store area in a variable, you should update it when you set the radius.  It shouldn't be independently set from "setArea".  Otherwise, you're vulnerable to inconsistency.  Also, a note from Josh Bloch's "Effective Java".  While your toString should take advantage of this "calculated area" rather than replicating the calculation, you shouldn't have toString call anything in your public API.  That would be an issue if, for instance, you overrode getArea, which would mean it would behave differently than your Circle.toString expects.  That's why I put the private "calculateArea" in there.

Answer (score 0):

Pass `radius` instead of `area` in the `setArea` method:

```
public void setArea( double radius )  
{
    area = (radius)*(radius)*Math.PI;
}
```

for complete code- http://pastebin.com/jggRrUFd

Answer (score 0):

This is my version of the Circle_Math Class, with entry validation and with the minimum number of lines / operations and memory space to get the job done. Please leave a comment if you want.

```
public class circle {
    static double rad;

    public circle() {
        rad = 0;
    }

    public static void setRad() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            while (!sc.hasNextDouble()) {
                sc.next();// this code is to skip the exception created 
            }
            rad = sc.nextDouble();
        } while (rad < 0);

        System.out.println("radius value is:" + rad);

    }

    public static double getCirclearea() {
        return rad * rad * Math.PI;
    }

    public static double getCircumference() {
        return 2 * Math.PI * rad;
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you please improve your code formatting? Read more at http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Circle {
    // variable PI is readable only;
    // constant value
    public static final double PI = 3.14;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter raduis: ");
        double raduis = input.nextDouble();

        double area = PI * raduis * raduis;
        System.out.print("Circle area = " + area);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static double getAreaOfCircle(int radius){
        return Math.PI*radius*radius;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

You originally set the `area` to be 0. You created a method to change that, but never called it. So call it. Change this:

```
public String toString() {
    return "The radius of the circle is: " + radius + ", and the area is: " + area;
}
```

to this:

```
public String toString() {
    setArea(area); // change the value of the area
    return "The radius of the circle is: " + radius + ", and the area is: " + area;
}
```

Comment: That wouldn't even compile. And it makes no sense to modify the state of an object in a toString() method.

Comment: @JBNizet Yeah I read the method wrong. I thought `setArea(area)` returned a String. I updated my answer. And I'm not looking to modify his class, which makes no sense for the most part; I'm just trying to fix the problem he's talking about.